# PHP MongoDB Driver and Aggregations

Tags: php, mongodb

I am at my first steps with mongoDB and php, trying to figure out how aggregations works. I have an approximate idea on how to use them from the command line but I am trying to translate this for the php driver. I am using the restaurants dexample DB, a list of records like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59a5211e107765480896f3f8"),
"address" : {
    "building" : "284",
    "coord" : [
        -73.9829239,
        40.6580753
    ],
    "street" : "Prospect Park West",
    "zipcode" : "11215"
},
"borough" : "Brooklyn",
"cuisine" : "American",
"grades" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-11-19T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 11
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 2
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2012-12-05T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 13
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2012-05-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 11
    }
],
"name" : "The Movable Feast",
"restaurant_id" : "40361606"
```

}

I just want to count how many restaurants for location, what I am doing is

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->myNewDb->restaurants;
$results = $collection->aggregate(
    [
        'name' => '$name'
    ],
    [
        '$group' => [
            'cuisine' => ['sum' => '$sum']
        ]
    ]
);
```

and I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' 
with message '$pipeline is not a list (unexpected index: "name")'
```

any idea? I can't find any good documentation on php.net.

thanks
M

Comment: What do you mean "translate"? Just about every language has really simple things to interchange with the widely available JavaScript Object Notation samples. The basic premise is every `{}` or even `[]` gets replaced with `[]` or `array()` using PHP. So with that in mind you are not even coming close to following the syntax. `$group` needs an `_id`. And I have no idea what you think `['name' => '$name']` is supposed to do. Perhaps you should even state what your expected output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look into [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), and you will see, that the pipelines must be passed as an array.

The `aggregate` method accepts two parameters `$pipelines` and `$options` (`public function aggregate(array $pipeline, array $options = [])`).

Also as was mentioned before, the `$group` must have the `_id` element.

> Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next
>   stage a document for each distinct grouping. The output documents
>   contain an _id field which contains the distinct group by key. The
>   output documents can also contain computed fields that hold the values
>   of some accumulator expression grouped by the $group‘s _id field.
>   $group does not order its output documents.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

So your code must look like this:

```
$results = $collection->aggregate([
    [
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => '$cuisine',
            'sum' => ['$sum' => 1],
            'names' => ['$push' => '$name']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

This code groups documents by `cuisine` element, counts the items and collects all `name` values into array.

Comment: @user3174311 You are welcome. Sorry for not well answer (which was before), but I also new on  MongoDB.